# Extracting function calls from an expression

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, expression-manipulation

I have an expression like this:

```
expr = F[0, 1] + 2 F[0, 0] - 17*F[2, 0]
```

and I want to transform it to a list consisting of all function calls with its arguments:

```
MyList = {F[0, 1], F[0, 0], F[2, 0]}
```

Does anyone know a clever way to do this in *Mathematica*?

My currently best solution is using ToString and do string-manipulations, but it is defintivly very slow and ugly.

Comment: For this example, Variables works i.e. Variables@expr

Answer (score 8, accepted):

E.g. using [`Cases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Cases.html):

```
Cases[expr, _F, Infinity]
```

> `{F[0, 0], F[0, 1], F[2, 0]}`

Note that the 3rd argument is the levelspec. See e.g. `expr//FullForm` why it's needed

**EDIT** (I wasn't careful!)

Note that this does not work for

```
expr = F[0,0]
```

as by default, `Cases` does not match the whole expression (it starts at level 1).

If that could be the case, you can use:

```
Cases[expr, _F, {0,Infinity}]
```

Also, see @YvesKlett's comment for levelspec `-1` (or `{0,-1}`).

Comment: This is wonderfully simple. And is motivating me to learn more the deep secrets of this great language. Thanks alot!!

Comment: I am glad you like it & I am kinda proud you take that as a start learning more about MMA (or whatever that language is called these days)! Don't accept to hastily, there might be other (maybe even nicer ways) to get what you like, you don't want to scare them away, do you? :) (and try to be active in here, that's how I learnt a lot!)

Comment: Perhaps add `Cases[expr, F[___], -1]` for variety?

Comment: @YvesKlett @PinguinDirk I'm curious...can the approach be expanded for an expression that has, say, functions `F` ,`G` and `H` + others, but without naming them and using `Or` ?

Comment: @PlaysDice: well, as long as you can make a pattern, it should work. Is there a concrete example you have in mind? (I would suggest not using capitals for that, as many of them are reserved (such as `E`, `C`, `D`,...)

Comment: @PinguinDirk  using OP as a template, `expr=func1[0,1]+ 2 elephant[2,3] - 17*unicorns[5,6]`  but without using `func1|elephant|unicorns` in `Cases`

Comment: @PlaysDice: well, assuming you want to retrieve the functions on the second but last level (and thus: not nested like `func1[0,func2[1]]`), you could e.g. use `Cases[expr, _, {-2}]`. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @PinguinDirk  yes, that's it exactly.  Thanks!  I think it also works for OP.

Comment: @PlaysDice: based on the example he gave I figured that the identifying pattern of the items to select is the head `F`. Thus my solution. But you are right, assuming he doesn't nest, it will work just as well.